# C++ Builder: "Unresolved external" error when using Clang compiler (__InitExceptBlockLDTC)

Tags: clang, linker-errors, c++builder, 32-bit

When developing a 32-bit application in C++ Builder using the Clang compiler, I encounter the following errors:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__InitExceptBlockLDTC' referenced from...
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2):

This can be resolved by adding the following path to the library path setting:

```
(Project -> Options -> C++ (Shared Options) -> Library Path):
```

$(BDSLIB)\win32c\debug

Comment: I also got the above error when using bcc32 and accidentally used the win32c library path, i.e. linked with clang libraries, instead of the classic ones.